# Sorting ansible output

Tags: sed, ansible

Below is my ansible task output.

```
TASK [debug]     **************************************************************************************************** **************************************
ok: [server01] => {
    "my_updates.stdout_lines": [
        "",
        "",
        "Title : Definition Update for Windows Defender Antivirus - KB2267602 (Definition 1.297.486.0)",
        "",
        "",
        ""
    ]
}
ok: [server02] => {
    "my_updates.stdout_lines": [
        "",
        "",
        "Title : 2020-08 Cumulative Update for Windows Server 2016 for x64-based Systems",
        "",
        "",
        ""
    ]
}
```

I only want entries

```
Definition Update for Windows Defender Antivirus - KB2267602 (Definition 1.297.486.0)
2020-08 Cumulative Update for Windows Server 2016 for x64-based Systems
```

So i tried below method,

```
   - name: Fetch Update List
     shell: echo {{ my_updates.stdout_lines }} | tr -s '  ' | sed 's/[][]//g' | sed 's/u,//g' | sed 's/u //g' | sed 's/  u//g' | sed 's/),/)/g'
     delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
     register: my_sec_result
     when: ansible_os_family == "Windows" and my_updates.stdout_lines | length |int   > 0

   - debug:
      var: my_sec_result.stdout_lines
```

but this wont help, it gives me below output

```
TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [server01] => {
    "my_sec_result.stdout_lines": [
        "Title : Definition Update for Windows Defender Antivirus - KB2267602 (Definition 1.297.486.0) "
    ]
}
ok: [server02] => {
    "my_sec_result.stdout_lines": [
        "Title : 2020-08 Cumulative Update for Windows Server 2016 for x64-based Systems "
    ]
}
```

How to get only these Entries, At present only one entry each found on each server. There can be multiple entries.

```
Definition Update for Windows Defender Antivirus - KB2267602 (Definition 1.297.486.0)
2020-08 Cumulative Update for Windows Server 2016 for x64-based Systems
```

Comment: You could set `ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=json` and generate a JSON output and parse it later using JSON aware tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your initial list, reject lines which are empty strings then remove the prepending "Title : " with the `regexp_replace` filter. The following task does it all in one:

```yaml
- name: Display updates
      debug:
        msg: "{{ my_updates.stdout_lines | reject('eq', '') | map('regex_replace', 'Title : (.*)', '\\g<1>') | list }}"
```

Update: As pointed out by @Vladimir, in this case your can replace `reject` with `select` for a cleaner template string:

```yaml
  - name: Display updates
      debug:
        msg: "{{ my_updates.stdout_lines | select() | map('regex_replace', 'Title : (.*)', '\\g<1>') | list }}"
```

Comment: It's possible to use `select()` instead of  `reject('eq', '')`.

Comment: How to use `select()`?

Comment: Works fine, Thanks a lot.